# how to convert jpeg file to pdf file in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, jpeg

I want to convert jepg file into pdf file in an iphone application...

Do anyone know any link or tutorial or any idea about this?

Comment: Do you done this job? please share your code

Comment: its been 4 years brother . I dont have that code but surly the answer stated here helped me a lot @SubhashSharma

Comment: thanks brother, i did it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you can do is load the image file and draw it into a newly created PDF context:

1. Load the JPEG file into a `UIImage`.
2. Create a new PDF context with `CGPDFContextCreate()` or `CGPDFContextCreateWithURL()`.
3. Add a page to the PDF context with `CGPDFContextBeginPage()`.
4. Draw the image into the PDF context. You will probably have to play a bit with the coordinate systems and the size of the image, depending on how you want the image to appear in the PDF.
5. Call `CGPDFContextEndPage()` and `CGPDFContextClose()`.